# connection between odd primes and a certain q-series

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, conjectures

I posed a conjecture about odd primes and a certain q-series[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395811/conjecture-about-primes-and-a-certain-q-series).I thought it would be more appropriate ,if I could ask the converse of the aforementioned problem .

Is $p$ an odd prime iff $$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{4n+1})^p}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi(n)\,q^n$$

such that $$\phi(n)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$ is true for all natural numbers $n\in\mathbb{N}$ except at multiples of $p$.

I've experimentally verified the conjecture for many values of p,and it seems to hold.Independent verification would be greatly appreciated.This conjecture seems to point to a deep connection between primes and modular forms,which I was not able to prove.Outlining a proof or connection between the particular q-series above and odd primes will be appreciated.

Comment: The following examples explain the property for prime $3$ and $5$.
$$\frac{1}{(q;q^4)_{\infty}^3}=1 + 3q +6q^2 + \color{brown}{10}q^3 + 15q^4 + 24q^5+ \color{brown}{37}q^6+\dots$$                                             
$$\frac{1}{(q;q^4)_{\infty}^5}=1 + 5q +15q^2 + 35q^3 + 70q^4 + \color{brown}{131}q^5+ 235q^6+405q^7+\dots$$

Comment: So you know that it never happens that the coefficient of degree $np$ term is divisible by $p$? As I said, the fact that the other coefficients are divisible by the prime $p$ follows immediately from Freshman's dream.

Comment: But why is the infinite product $$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{4n+1})^p}$$ the only one that's unique,in the sense that it is the only one that obeys the property.

Comment: In my answer I show that the coefficient of $q^{27}$ in $\dfrac{1}{(q;q^4)_{\infty}^3}$ is divisible by three. Is this in violation of what you expected? Have you calculated that series up to $q^{27}$?

Comment: Similarly the coefficient of $q^{65}$ in $\dfrac{1}{(q;q^4)_{\infty}^5}$ is divisible by $5$. This is because the coefficient of $Q^{13}$ in the series $\psi(Q)$ is $=5$.

Comment: BTW: As a moderator I feel compelled to ask, whether you think this should be merged with the earlier version. Reasking the same question is frowned upon here.

Answer (score 2):

In the ring of formal power series $\Bbb{Z}[[q]]$ the left hand side is (by Freshman's Dream)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi_p(k)q^k=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{4n+1})^p}\equiv\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{p(4n+1)})}\pmod p.
$$
This is clearly a power series in $q^p$, so $\phi_p(k)$ is divisible by $p$ whenever $k$ is not divisible by $p$.

Let $p=3$. We have
$$
\psi(Q):=\prod_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{1-Q^{4n+1}}=\frac1{(1-Q)(1-Q^5)(1-Q^9)}+\ \text{terms with $Q^{13}$ or higher powers.}
$$
Expanding this gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac1{(1-Q)(1-Q^5)(1-Q^9)}&=(1+Q+Q^2+\cdots)(1+Q^5+Q^{10}+\cdots)(1+Q^9+\cdots)\\
&=1+Q+Q^2+Q^3+Q^4+2Q^5+2Q^6+2Q^7+2Q^8+3Q^9\\
&+\ \text{terms with $Q^{10}$ or higher}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Again the Freshman's dream implies that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi_3(k)q^k=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-q^{4n+1})^3}\equiv\psi(q^3)\pmod 3.
$$
Here 
$$
\psi(q^3)=1+q^3+q^6+q^9+q^{12}+2q^{15}+2q^{18}+2q^{21}+2q^{24}+3q^{27}
$$
plus higher degree terms. Therefore $\phi_3(27)$ is divisible by three even though $27$ is also divisible by three. So we cannot say that $\phi_3(k)$ is divisible by three if and only if $3\nmid k$.

Comment: Taking the factor $(1-Q^{13})^{-1}$ into account shows that $\psi(Q)=\cdots+5Q^{13}+\cdots$. This means that $5\mid \phi_5(65)$.

Comment: Very nice disproof indeed,+1